# Get user root directory from windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a Windows Service written in C#.  I need to add a file to each user directory.  How can I find the path to start in?  I realize this is really dumb but this is what I'm currently doing:

```
  if (Directory.Exists("C:\\Users"))
  {
    path = "C:\\Users";
  }
  else if (Directory.Exists("C:\\Documents and Settings"))
  {
    path = "C:\\Documents and Settings";
  }
```

I've looked at the special folders: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx

None of them seem to return what I need.  For example, ApplicationData is returning the path to the System32 directory.  I presume this is because it is running as a windows service.  The code I'm currently using works for the few tests I've done.  It just seems like there should be a more intelligent (error proof) way of getting this path.

Another thought...maybe there is a registry key that will give me what I'm looking for?  Hmmm

Comment: I wonder how possible it is for users to exist in other directories too.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's possible...that's why I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: No; I mean for users to exist in multiple directories.

Comment: You should never use hardcoded path like the above, as they are not consistent over OS versions. While newer versions of Windows do support backward compatibility by making soft/hardlinks to the legacy folder names, there is no guarantee it will always be the case

Comment: @Tseng: That's exactly why he's asking this question.

Comment: Why do these files need to exist in each user's folder structure? Do they need separate copies? It feels like you're trying to solve a problem with a *solution* you've devised to an unknown problem you've not told us about.

Answer (score 1):

I found this under Win7 registry.   XP looks to have the same registry keys, but the values have "All Users" profile within it.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders]
"Common Desktop"="C:\\Users\\Public\\Desktop"
"Common Start Menu"="C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu"
"CommonVideo"="C:\\Users\\Public\\Videos"
"CommonPictures"="C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures"
"Common Programs"="C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs"
"CommonMusic"="C:\\Users\\Public\\Music"
"Common Administrative Tools"="C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Administrative Tools"
"Common Startup"="C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup"
"Common Documents"="C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents"
"OEM Links"="C:\\ProgramData\\OEM Links"
"Common Templates"="C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Templates"
"Common AppData"="C:\\ProgramData"
```

Comment: A service doesn't run under the context of a user, so how would this environmental variable exist?

Comment: Is the Service running under System?

Answer (score 0):

I might not have understood you completely but I think you just need to get the location where you are running from and then get the Root off of it.

```
Path.GetPathRoot(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

**Update**

The [special folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) is what you need to research.  There isn't a simple go-here do-this because your question wasn't detailed enough.  If the service is running as a specific user or as system then makes a difference.  Also, you didn't specify how it was being used so that would matter.  Is it a place to hold config files vs temp location to write files vs should anyone else want to get at the folder?  All these things matter so if you add some additional details then I will update my answer.

Comment: I believe he's trying to access all profiles users, but since he's running under a system account, he doesn't know how to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

How about `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` and key `ProfilesDirectory`? It points to `%SystemDrive%\Users` on my PC. Just not sure which versions of Windows have this key (7 & 10 do).